# Handle GUI window changes

Tags: user-interface, process, autoit, pid

I'm doing an automation script for installation wizards using AutoIt. I'm trying to handle window changes in some way.

Can some one explain how these GUI's work?

When I click on the Next button it looks just like the components in the GUI is beeing changed. Is this tha case? Or is a new window created and the old destroyed?

I've noticed that the process ID is the same for all windows.

I'm sure there is some way to know which "state" the GUI is in, or which step?

By the way. All the windows has the same title.

Thanks
/Anders

Comment: Where is the problem? Just Use ControlClick or ControlCommand or Controlsend to interact with the window.

Comment: Well, The problem is that, for every "dialog" or "window" in an installation wizard, I want to write "WinWaitActive()" to another file. In the installation wizard, all the titles are the same. It is just the text and controls that is being changed. So there for my question. How does it work? Because the window never gets killed or recreated all the dialogues has the same handle. I want some unique ID for each "window/dialog". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be dependant on the program you are automating.

The easiest approach would be to look at what changes in the GUI between stages, likely candidates are if there is a label that is giving instructions for that step, or a button that has text changing (e.g. if the button says "Finish" then you know your at the end).

Most installer programs have child windows for grouping the controls of each stage. These are typically implemented as dialog resources (as can be seen when using something like reshacker on them). So although the window remains the same, the panels are being created/destroyed as appropriate. This is a very neat method of doing it, for the obvious reason that you don't need to have to code to create/destroy a lot of controls. Resource created dialogs don't have nice class names like windows sometimes do though, so this may not be a reliable way to check the state.